# Check if twitter application installed

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I'm developing an application and I need to write a message in **Twitter** (when user clicks on twitter icon).

How can I detect does Twitter application installed or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check using `canOpenURL(_:)`.

**Swift 3.0**

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"twitter://"))) {
    print("Twitter is installed")
}
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"twitter://"))) {
    print("Twitter is installed")
}
```

Comment: This only works if you first declare which apps your app intends to open in the `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>facebook</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the app can open an URL on that application

```
extension UIApplication {
        class func tryURL(_ urls: [String]) {
            let application = UIApplication.shared
            for urlString in urls {
                if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                    if application.canOpenURL(url) {
                        //Do your stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```